# Font not changing CSS

Tags: fonts

Currently using Django with bootstrap 4. For whatever reason, I cannot get the font-family to change through my main.css file. I can change other attributes, but font does not seem to work.

If I change the font-family in my other files, it works. I just cannot change it through my main.css.

What am I doing wrong?

index.html

```html
{% load static %}

<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/main.css' %}">
...
```

main.css

```css
body {
   font-family: "Times New Roman", Georgia, serif !important;
}
```